# What audio usb interface do I need to play guitar pro with guitar rig?

Tags: audio-interfaces, guitar, guitar-rig

i'd like to play with Guitar Rig sounds while running Guitar Pro to exercise.

At the moment i'm using Rocksmith Cable with Asio4All to connect the guitar for Guitar Rig, but Asio4All is exclusive and Guitar Pro doesn't emit any sound.
With an usb audio interface (like [Yamaha AUDIOGRAM 3](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/music-production/interfaces/audiogram/audiogram3/?mode=model)) will I be able to play both?

If the answer is Yes, what (cheap) audio interfaces do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is what you're looking for:
[Scarlett 2i2](http://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-2i2)

This is a REALLY good USB interface, that I've personally used for about 2-3 years(I actually have 2 of them). It is also the same, or lower, than the one you linked, depending on where you purchase it from.